# Control threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

We are developing a Python 2.7 program that it has several threads. We have also make a thread that supervises that all threads are properly running. It is essentially as simple as this:

```
all_my_threads = [controlador, usb, telegram, watch, registro, pantalla, hilo1, auto, authentication]

while True:

  for thread in all_my_threads:

    if (thread.isAlive()):

        print (str(thread) + " is alived.")

    else:

        print (str(thread) + " is not alived.")
        print ("Stating " + str(thread) + " thread.")
        thread.start()

  time.sleep(15)
```

When all threads are running we get:

> Thread(Thread-1, started 1943008212) is  alived.
>   Thread(Thread-2, started 1943008368) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-3, started 1926231152) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-4, started 1934619760) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-5, started 1961882736) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-6, started 1951396976) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-7, started 1971758192) is alived.
>   Thread(Thread-9, started 1982223472) is alived.

The problem is that we have seen that when a thread breaks for any reason the piece of code I have shared tries to start again the thread, but it crashes with this error:

> threads can only be started once

So something must be wrong in this piece of code...

Any idea or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance;

Ander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather handle the exceptions inside the Thread than trying to restart it. You can check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

It is much more simple and pythonic to do so.

In fact you can't restart a thread and the majority of platforms don't support it.

When a thread finished, its stack is dead; its parent will be flagged or signaled; once it's joined, its resources are erased. To restart it you need to recreate everything. Which is easier if you create a new thread.

You can create your a subclass that recreates threads:

```
class RestartThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._args, self._kwargs = args, kwargs
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def clone(self):
        return RestartThread(*args, **kwargs)
```

and now you can clone your thread in case of an exception raised:

```
if not test_thread.is_alive():
    test_thread = test_thread.clone()
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you help me implementing your RestartThread class to my purpouse, I am not very familiar with classes and I don't know how to call them correctly. So I get error while doing my_thread.clone()